# Checking a cell is Not IsEmpty in If Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I can't my nested If Loop working right.

I want the data in the TestTable column coped over IF there is a figure in there, if the cell is blank, I Want it to go to next i.

There are no runtime errors however, for some reason it is just copying every cell over, completely ignoring the NOT IsEmpty part?

```
Sub MoveData
Dim InTbl As ListObject, TeTbl As ListObject, i As Long, LastRow As Long, AmendedCCY

Set InTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("Input").ListObject
Set TeTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("TestTab").ListObject
Set AmendedCCY = InTbl.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange

LastRow = AmendedCCY.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To LastRow

        If Not IsEmpty("Input[Amended]") Then
         TeTbl.DataBodyRange(i, 2).Value = InTbl.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Value
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

I've also used the following:

`If ("Input[Amended]") <> "" Then`

`If IsEmpty("Input[Amended]") = False Then`

I guess there is an issue with the ("Input[Amended]") but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Have you tried `debug.print` on the different variables?  Have you checked that cells are truly empty? i.e. containing a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Input[Amended]"` is just a constant string, filled with characters, hence it won't ever be empty.

You need to access the cell, containing the information you're looking for, something like:

```
IsEmpty(InTbl.DataBodyRange(i, 4).Value)
```

Obviously I don't know if you should look in column 4 or in another one, so please change that value `4` accordingly.